# The singular values of the best rank-$k$ approximation to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-rank, svd, approximation-theory

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ be a complex matrix. Let $B_k$ be a best rank-$k$ approximation to $A$ such that
\begin{equation*}
B_k\in\arg\min\limits_{{\rm rank}(B)=k}||A-B||_F,
\end{equation*}
where $||\cdot||_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm. Then, I guess $k$ largest singular values of $B_k$ is identical with the $k$ largest singular values of $A$ and other singular values of $B_k$ are all zero. Is my conjecture correct? Can anyone help me prove this?

Comment: By pre- and post- multiplication by unitary matrices, you may as well assume $A$ is diagonal. Then any besta pproximation to $\|A-B_k\|$  will be by diagonal $B_k$, and so on.

Comment: why the best rank-k approximation to diagonal matrix should be also diagonal?

Comment: The map that replaces off-diagonal entries with zero is an orthogonal projection onto the set of diagonal matrices.  So you are left with a combinatorial problem, of selecting which $k$ diagonal elements to preserve and which others to set to 0.

Comment: the feasible set is $\{B|{\rm rank(B)}=k\}$. A rank-$k$ matrix may have more than $k $ nonzero diagonal entries. So, what's the usage of the orthogonal projection here. could you provide more details?